Chrome Custom Tabs,java.lang.IllegalStateException: setPackageName must be called before bindSessionToPostMessageService
In my project, I use Chrome Custom Tabs and expect to establish communication through requestPostMessageChannel, but when executing this line of code, an error occurs: java.lang.IllegalStateException: setPackageName must be called before bindSessionToPostMessageService. After tracing the code, the problem seems to arise when executing this.mRemote.transact(11, _data, _reply, 0). This error only occurs in this project; other projects run smoothly. I have tried many methods but cannot solve the issue.
My gradle version is 7.5, agp is 7.4.2, and browser is 1.8.0.
        var mmsession : CustomTabsSession? = null
        val connection: CustomTabsServiceConnection = object : CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
            override fun onCustomTabsServiceConnected(
                componentName: ComponentName,
                customTabsClient: CustomTabsClient
            ) {
                // 创建CustomTabsSession
                mmsession = customTabsClient.newSession(object : CustomTabsCallback() {
                    override fun onMessageChannelReady(extras: Bundle?) {
                        super.onMessageChannelReady(extras)
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "onMessageChannelReady")
                        val result : Int? = mmsession?.postMessage("First message sent", Bundle().also {
                            it.putString("navigateTo","https://sayedelabady.github.io/")
                        })
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Result : $result")
                    }

                    override fun onPostMessage(message: String, extras: Bundle?) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity","message : $message")
                        if (message.contains("navigation command")) {
                            val msg = "{\"navigateTo\":\"\",\"time\":\"${System.currentTimeMillis()}\"}"
                            val suc = mmsession?.postMessage(msg,null)
                            Log.d("MainActivity","postmessage : $suc")
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onRelationshipValidationResult(
                        relation: Int,
                        requestedOrigin: Uri,
                        result: Boolean,
                        extras: Bundle?
                    ) {
                        super.onRelationshipValidationResult(relation, requestedOrigin, result, extras)
                        Log.d("MainActivity","Relationship result: $result  requestedOrigin: $requestedOrigin")
                        super.onRelationshipValidationResult(
                            relation,
                            requestedOrigin,
                            result,
                            extras
                        )
                    }

                    override fun onNavigationEvent(navigationEvent: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"NavigationEvent : $navigationEvent")
                    }
                })
                // 请求post message channel
                Log.d("MainActivity","current s L $mmsession")
                if (mmsession != null) {
                    mmsession!!.requestPostMessageChannel(Uri.parse("https://bp-web-newbie.singapore.ai-transsion.com/chat"))
                }

Has anyone encountered the same problem and solved it?
